# Is it possible to dynamically create azure timer functions?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm working on creating a scheduler app to replace cronicle. I'd like to use Azure functions since that's the route our company is looking at going.

In brief, I want to build an app that would dynamically create an Azure timer function for each scheduled item. At the set interval, the function would call a REST endpoint with some information.

Is it possible using some kind of Azure API to dynamically create and delete an Azure timer function?

Comment: Like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/web-apps/create-function ?

Comment: At first glance, that might just be it! Thanks!!!